# ListView add filter on another ListView item selection changed

Tags: xaf

I'm currently studying XAF (expressApp Framework) for my work and theres not much good tutorials on the web about it so I went here to ask.

I have a Customers table and a Product table with many-many relationship. 
I created a dashboard view where I displayed listviews for both Customers and Products. What I want to know is how can I changed the values on Product listview or add filter to it whenever I select a customer?

I managed to acces the SelectionChanged event of the Customers listview by creating a view controller.

```
    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
        View.SelectionChanged += ViewOnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void ViewOnSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var id = ((Customers) View.CurrentObject).Oid;
    }
```

The event works everytime I  select an item in the listview.

I was planning to filter the Products listview using the Customers' Oid. 
How will I able to do that?

And also if you can give me some links for a good XAF tutorial, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: There is [this discussion](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q504703) in the DevExpress support center.

Comment: And there are various tutorials [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113577)

Answer (score 0):

To apply a filter to a ListView you need to add criteria to  collectionsource. See the link: 
 https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112722